# Is entropy of the universe constant?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, entropy, space-expansion, universe

Studying the thermodynamics of the early universe we arrived at the conclusion that entropy of the universe has to be constant for the entropy to be a function of state. But from basilar thermodynamics we know that irreversible processes cause an increase in the entropy of the universe. How both things can be true? What logical passage did I lose? Can the expansion of the universe be involved in this apparent contradiction?

Comment: Can you justify the comment *Studying the thermodynamics of the early universe we arrived at the conclusion that entropy of the universe has to be constant for the entropy to be a function of state.* with a reference?

Comment: The growth of entropy is for closed system, the Universe looks to be an open one. As far I know, its entropy actually decreases due to the expansion and of the subsequent cooling.

Answer (score 0):

Good question!

You could have been more explicit about the assumptions you're making, but I understand what you mean because I wondered about this for a long time too.  I bumped it up from -2 to -1, although it would be good if you could fix the spelling typos.

You are correct that when cosmologists model the expansion of the universe, they almost always use an equation of state which implies that entropy is constant.

For some reason, despite years of searching, I've never actually seen this point made explicitly in any internet forums or articles about cosmology, despite it continually causing widespread confusion.  But if you look at the standard FLRW equation of state used, the reason is simple:  it's derived from the ideal gas law.  Yes, that's right... nearly all of their models are based on the idealization that the evolution of all matter and energy in the universe can be described by the dirt simple equation PV = nRT.

There are two assumptions built into the ideal gas law:

1. You can safely ignore all dissipative forces
   and
2. The system has already come to equilibrium, and is therefore at maximum entropy

Given these two assumptions, which really both boil down to the same assumption (that nothing relevant to what you're studying is changing fast enough to depart from equilibrium), it should be no surprise that it's impossible to generate any new entropy in such models.

Now, you might be thinking "wait, that can't be right... haven't I seen scenarios in basic thermodynamics where the entropy of an ideal gas changes"?  Yes, that's true.  But there are two very different reasons why the entropy of a system can change:

1. Because there was dissipation, an irreversible change to the system that turns useful work into wasted heat
   or
2. Because the system was open, and entropy was allowed to flow in or out of it.

If entropy changes, it's always due to one of those two.  With an ideal gas, you can only ever have case 2 happen.  And if case 2 happens, the entropy of the universe is still constant because any increase in entropy in the system is always exactly cancelled out by a corresponding decrease in the entropy of the environment and vice versa.  This type of change is always reversible, and just has to do with considering only a subsystem of a larger system rather than the whole thing.

Since the universe is a closed system (meaning, it has no surrounding environment it can exchange energy or entropy with), #2 cannot happen.  And #1 cannot happen as long as we're treating everything as an ideal gas and ignoring entropy.  Therefore, entropy is constant... QED.

Okay, you might still be thinking:  what if I have a box with two compartments, where one of them contains and ideal gas and the other a vacuum... doesn't entropy increase if I remove the barrier to let the gas fill the vacuum?  Yes, that's true... that is an irreversible process.  But during the brief moment when the gas rapidly expands into the empty chamber, it departs from equilibrium so far that it completely violates the assumptions of an ideal gas... in other words, PV=nRT is *not* true during that expansion, ie it is not an ideal gas while it's expanding so it's fine if it generates entropy in that case.

How does this apply to cosmology?  Cosmologists use the FLRW equation of state to model how the universe expands during nearly all epochs of the expansion of the universe.  Therefore, they do assume that as the universe expands entropy remains constant.  The only exception to that I know of is when modeling the brief inflationary epoch hypothesized to have happened before the Hot Big Bang began.  That's because according to the theory of inflation, the expansion during that period was so rapid that the universe departed from equilibrium and an enormous amount of entropy was generated.  Same as with the gas expanding into the 2nd chamber in the previous paragraph.

So yes, most basic cosmology equations assume constant entropy... despite the fact that in the actual universe, entropy is always increasing.  Why is that?  Because cosmologists are usually interested in things like the curvature of the universe, the ratio of matter, energy, dark matter, and dark energy, anisotropy in the cosmic background radiation, etc.  None of these things require taking entropy into account... so they can come to valid conclusions about the things they are modeling without caring that they are making an approximation which does not allow for the possibility of entropy increasing.

Sorry this got so long, I'm almost done.  The only part of your question I haven't addressed yet is:  if that's all true, then how the heck does entropy actually increase?!  Despite very widespread confusion over this, it really has nothing to do with the expansion of the universe.  It increases for the same reason it increases in any system.  Fuel gets used up, things tend to progress from ordered to disordered, energy flows from hotter bodies to cooler bodies.  In the end, all energy gradients will have dissipated so that everything has reached its maximum entropy state and all parts of the universe are fully at equilibrium with each other.  In other words, we will reach the state that most cosmology models assume we have already reached... the point at which entropy is no longer increasing.  Cosmologists look at things from a bird's eye view, on the largest scale possible... at that scale, everything already looks pretty homogenous so it's not unreasonable to treat it as approximately in equilibrium.  It's only when you zoom in far enough that you start seeing all of the nooks and crannies where there is more energy in some parts and less in others, or where it's hotter or colder:  the clusters of dark matter, the galaxies, the stars.  When things *actually* reach equilibrium, all of that nicely ordered structure will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not constant. Universe starts from a state with very low entropy and will "finish" with a state of very high entropy. See my question to-day on the "entropy paradox", and answer by Gandalf 61. See as well "Entropy as an arrow of time" in Wikipedia.

Answer (score -2):

The statement that entropy is a state function is only true for a system...the overall entropy of a process depends on the path taken as the entropy of the surrounding is just Q/T...So the thing happening is that in an irreversible process the increase in entropy of the surrounding is more than the decrement in the entropy of the system and thus an overall increment takes place...

Answer (score -4):

Entropy, which is closely related to energy, only makes sense for closed systems within the universe. The energy of the universe does not make sense because energy is the time component of a vector, and vectors defined at different points cannot be summed. Likewise the entropy of the universe is does not make sense.

Comment: Of which vector is energy a time component of?

Comment: @Ezio, energy is the time component of the energy-momentum 4-vector

Comment: So what exactly has energy in GR as part of the EM tensor have to do with the fact that the entropy of the universe is increasing?

Comment: @Ezio, as I have already answered, there is no such quantity as the entropy of the universe. Since it does not exist, it cannot be increasing.

Comment: Says who? The universe as far as I know is itself a closed system. So it's a matter of pure statistics that entropy is increasing...

Comment: Says the mathematics of general relativity and the definition of a closed system. If you don't know what those things are, then you are not in a position to comment.

Comment: I know what the math of GR is. Mostly a bunch of index corrdinate gymnastics that more often than not produces non physical results. The universe doesn't exchange energy in GR regardless, so entropy is increasing...